# Disabling focus on EditText

Tags: android

I'm using the `setOnFocusChangeListener` but I'm looking for something more viable for my application. Currently this is what I'm using.

```
if(primaryCode == CodeCC)
                {
                    mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.keyboardview);
                    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, R.xml.symbol2keyboard));
                    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
                    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(symbol2Keyboard);

                    final EditText edit1 = (EditText)  mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.row1);
                    final EditText edit2 = (EditText)  mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.row2);
                    final EditText edit3 = (EditText)  mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.row3);
                    final EditText edit4 = (EditText)  mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.row4);

                    edit1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                            if(hasFocus)
                            {
                                edit2.setEnabled(false);
                            }else
                                edit2.setEnabled(true);

                        }
                    });
```

I'm wondering if there is something like, if I click `edit1`, `edit2` will be disabled. But when I click `edit2`, `edit2` will be enabled back but `edit3` will be disabled etc.

Right now, when `edit2` is enabled, I can't even click it or it doesn't allow the focus to be on `edit2`. Is it fixed that way or is there another way that I can work around with?

Thanks

```
Layout Code:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextselection"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/next" />

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textModeTab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/row1"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:inputType="text" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/row2"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/row1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:inputType="text" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/row3"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/row2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:inputType="text" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/row4"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/row3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:inputType="text" />


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/row4CB"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/row2"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/row2"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/row3CB"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/row1"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/row1"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row4CB"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/row1CB"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/row3"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/row3"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row4CB"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/row2CB"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/row4"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/row4"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row1CB"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row3CB"
                        android:text="Scroll"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/graphicsModeTab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/animationModeTab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. If you disable an element, it won't respond to any events, including focus events. You may still get focus on another element and edit2 should be enabled then, as edit1 will loose its focus. That works as designed.

I would not recommend to do that, but you can try to extend `Button` class to override its disabled behaviour. It should draw itself in disabled state, while being actually enabled. I can't provide any code example as I failed to implement it myself fast.

Check sources of `View` class and `Drawable` implementations.

Comment: Yeah activating another focus can allow me to re-enable what is disabled before. So there is no other way then just that?

Comment: Yes. I think the only possible way is to implement your own custom view which will have custom logic on handling events while being disabled.

Comment: Is there any reference for it? Or have you heard of it?

Comment: That would be great if you could.

Comment: Well, it seems to hard for a full-featured primer :) But  I will give some code though, just to point you to probably right direction.

Comment: Check edited comment. But I don't think that I helped you much. That won't be easy to do, except you know well how Android View system works.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you absolutely necessarily want this feature and cannot do without it:
What you can do is change your layout a bit.Place a transparent relative layout on top of each edit text.When an onclick of the edit text is triggerred,you can disable everything you want accordingly and also make the relative layout invisible and request focus on your edit text.Its slightly tedious but layout masking opens a a large number of possibiltiies for the sort of things you are trying.

If you want a code example,please add your layout code and comment on my answer.I'll update it.

**EDIT**: added code
there you go.I dont like the hack much,but it does what you want.You might have to tweak the keyboard opening to make it better.

The activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView row1, row2;
private EditText row1Et, row2Et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    row1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row1cover);
    row2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row2cover);
    row1Et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.row1);
    row2Et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.row2);

    row1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            row1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            row2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            row1Et.setEnabled(true);
            row2Et.setEnabled(false);
            row1Et.requestFocus();
            row1Et.performClick();// to open the key
            Log.d("disabled", "1 is disabled?:" + row1Et.isEnabled());
            Log.d("disabled", "2 is disabled?:" + row2Et.isEnabled());
        }
    });

    row2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            row2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            row1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            row1Et.setEnabled(false);
            row2Et.setEnabled(true);
            row2Et.requestFocus();
            row2Et.performClick();
            Log.d("disabled", "2 is disabled?:" + row2Et.isEnabled());
            Log.d("disabled", "1 is disabled?:" + row1Et.isEnabled());

        }
    });

    OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            } else {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

        }
    };
    row1Et.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    row2Et.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);

}
```

}

and layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backselection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="back" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextselection"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="next" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/textModeTab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row1cover"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/row1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/row1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row2cover"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/row2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/row1CB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/row2CB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've included my layout code. I tried to put a Relative Layout on the EditText but it does not allow me to resize it to the size of the edittext though